# Looking for a way to translate an application

Tags: c++, windows, localization

I'm starting to design an application and I'd like it to support several languages from the beginning to avoid having to change big amounts of code later on to enable multiple languages.

I've written early a C application for which the messages were in a *struct* so I'd have several header files with the translated strings which would be integrated into the application itself, so to add a new language I'd have to recompile.

What I'd like is to be able to have a localization system that allows me to translate the application and add new languages easily without having to recompile the application. Ideally with a pretty straightforward way of translating and testing the translation (like editing a text file and seeing the results back in the app), without having to depend on 3rd party tools for the translation.

I'm thinking about writing my own system for it, maybe based on XML for the files containing the translations for example, but I wonder if anybody has experience with this and would recommend a lightweight library that provides that I'd like (even if the translation is not so direct as editing a text file). I emphasize lightweight because I think the application itself is not going to weight more than a couple of megabytes.

It's going to be a Windows application, if that's relevant for the matter. As of now I still haven't decided on the graphic toolkit I use but it's probably that I'll use the default Windows offers without using a cross platform one (like wxWidgets, Qt, GTK+, ...). But it's not set in stone, if one offered significant advantages it'd consider it.

Comment: It depends on which GUI toolkit you are going to use. Literally all of them have internationalization and localization support. Specify the toolkit and you will get an answer.

Comment: Oh I see, I think I'll be using the native GUI that Windows offers without using any cross platform toolkit but it's not set in stone.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how lightweight is, but [qt has a good support for internationalization](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/internationalization.html).

Then you can use [QtLinguist](http://code.google.com/p/qtlinguistdownload/) to simply translate your text.

Answer (score 1):

Don't invent your own system. Internationalization (i18n) and localization (l10n) are almost always covered in some existing library.

If you develop for Windows, this link, [Globalizing and Localizing .NET Framework Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6270d0z.aspx), might prove useful.

Comment: seems he is doing C/C++ and not .NET

Comment: There are loads of libraries to choose from, but selecting one and getting it to work is in some cases harder than just writing a basic dictionary system.

Comment: @claptrap [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) is a framework and not a language. You can access .NET from several languages, C++ amongst others.

Comment: @ReturningTarzan It's always easier, and of course more fun, to start your own library. But maintaining it, until is mature enough, draws considerable resources. So, you're right, it takes effort to select an appropriate library in any case, but after that it pays off almost always.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll read through those docs. At first I thought about writing my own but since I'm not versed in the matter I really value your opinion.

Comment: @A.Row If it is really just a simple lookup system, you might be faster with a basic dictionary as ReturningTarzan suggested. But a full localization system is not only about text strings, but comprises sorting, date and time, numeric and money formats. It all depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: @OlafDietsche yes i know, but it is a rather heavy dependency to add in a C++ program just to get language support. The more dependencies, the more can go wrong and the more you need to install when install your product. Just my 2c. To each his own.

Comment: @claptrap Every additional library or framework adds a burden, but so does developing your own. If you know of a simpler approach, that would be great. I'm sure, @ A.Row, and me too, would love to see more answers. Please add your own, even if it advises against my suggestion. This helps to balance reasons. Anyway, thanks for sharing your view.